# How do you find out the latest news in fields other than your own?

Tags: soft-question

Most of us are at least somewhat curious about what's going on in areas of mathematics outside our own area of research.  If a significant breakthrough is made, and can be stated in language that we understand, then we would enjoy hearing about it.  Now, for truly fantastic breakthroughs like Fermat's Last Theorem or the Poincaré conjecture, the mathematical grapevine functions quite well and we all hear about it pretty quickly.  For anything below that level, however, I for one feel that there is no good way to find out what is going on in fields other than my own.  Every four years I seem to have the following conversation: "Did you hear?  So-and-so won the Fields Medal!"  "No.  And, uh, who in the world is so-and-so?"  Shameful.

What I'm wondering is, am I doing something wrong?  Does anyone else have a better way of keeping abreast, even at a superficial level, of what major advances are happening in other areas of mathematics?  At one time, *Mathematical Reviews* would select some articles or books for "Featured Reviews."  I really enjoyed Featured Reviews and learned about many interesting results this way.  However, MR stopped doing Featured Reviews after a while.  No official reason was given, but I have heard that one reason was that some people were treating Featured Reviews as judgments as to which papers/books were "the best," and that MR did not want to accept the responsibility for making such judgments, especially if they were going to be used for tenure and promotion decisions.  This is understandable, but unfortunate (from my point of view).

The series of books *What's Happening in the Mathematical Sciences* is also excellent.  However, producing an expository article of that quality takes a lot of time, and so *What's Happening* is necessarily limited in scope.  I would like to know what's happening in between issues of *What's Happening*.  If there are resources out there that others have found useful for keeping abreast of mathematical research news, I would like to hear about them.

Comment: How about Mathoverflow?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are just joking, but in case this was a serious comment, MathOverflow is not a forum for announcements of major results in mathematics.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's always hard to follow what's happening, especially in fields other than your own. I don't have any silver bullets, just a few time tested things that require serious work.

1. Talk to colleagues. If you are in a research department, always go to a colloquium. MR can be used both before and after the talk to tie it with what's been going on in the area.
   Go to seminar talks.
2. Conferences. Even browsing through the list of abstracts of invited addresses at AMS Sectional Meetings helps to keep you informed. Actually attending these talks and, especially, invited addresses at the Joint Math Meetings is even better: they feature people who have been doing important work recently. I imagine other Math Societies operate in a similar way. For the past few years, the JMM has run a secion on "Current events". Like the Cambridge "Perspectives in Mathematics" conference, they make the texts of all talks available.
3. Browse through new books and journals and read book reviews (the ones in the Bulletin of AMS play a role similar to the MR featured reviews, but are set in a wider context). One of the biggest draws of the JMM is the book sale. By browsing through new publications, one can get the vibes of what is happening; even better, you can probe other people's reaction to anything you find interesting but don't quite understand. Bourbaki Seminar has 18 talks a year on subjects of current research interest.
4. I've heard that some people religiously follow all new submissions on the arXiv, but I can't vouch for the benefits or effectiveness of this method. On the other hand, once you get a wind of some new developments, you can search the arXiv for papers and surveys, many of which never make it to print in spite of being helpful (in some respects, arXiv now fulfills the role formerly played by the Lecture Notes in Mathematics).
5. You can run a self-teach seminar if you have at least one (ideally, 3 or more) interested colleagues. This may be on the subject of a recent paper, survey, or a book. If your colleagues are in a different field, so much the better: they can teach you what's happening there, and you can teach them something in return.

Comment: Following the arXiv isn't particularly difficult; you can use an aggregator like Google reader and pick and choose which subjects you want to subscribe to.  (Unfortunately, you can't stop papers in multiple subjects from being listed multiple times.)

Comment: I do subscribe to the ArXiv, but I find that the volume of just the items in my field(s) of interest borders on overwhelming.  The same goes for blogs and journals.  I can maybe follow one or two blogs, but to find out what's happening in all of mathematics I'd have to sift through dozens of blogs in dozens of fields, and that is just not feasible for me.  Perhaps this is just a fact of life and there is no better solution, but I was hoping that there would be something like Featured Reviews or slashdot out there---someone who had already done the sifting, for the benefit of the community.

Comment: Yes, mathematics is just too big! I think that the AMS conferences, Bulletin and Notices are as close to a centralized and balanced view as you can get. Bloggers and indeed writers of featured reviews are doing the sifting according to _their_ interests (and expertise), not yours.

Answer (score 4):

I generally subscribe to good blogs updated at a reasonable frequency from multiple fields which I think is a pretty good way to keep abreast of the news in those fields.

[Here](http://www.academicblogs.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a big list of academic blogs which might be useful. ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20110819065218/http://www.academicblogs.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and also a [link for Mathematics/Statistics](https://web.archive.org/web/20090918085549/http://www.academicblogs.org:80/wiki/index.php/Mathematics/Statistics))

Comment: Another list of math blogs: http://www.onlinedegree.net/50-best-blogs-for-math-majors/ .  Ignore the ranking.

Comment: @Yuan, I have to comment--on that list is "Not Even Wrong."  Please, don't try to read that blog...  There's no math, the guy says he does physics but is hardly competent, and has published no more than a dozen papers in his carrier, only three or so in the past decade or two, most of which have almost no citations.  The guy is not taken seriously by anyone in the theoretical physics community...  I don't know how this guy keeps getting on every list of science blogs on the internet, but it drives me nuts.

Comment: @jeremy Please don't tell Qiaochu what he has to read. Since Woit's "Not Even Wrong" criticizes the string theory community for their hype and their failure to come up with any refutable predictions, he is viciously attacked by that establishment. They resort, just like you, to *ad hominem* attacks. Having written a dozen papers is quite respectable and your judgment "the guy is not taken seriously in the theoretical physics community" is unsupported slander.Anyway good scientific practice would be to address his criticism, and not to count his papers.[To be continued in next comment box]

Comment: @Georges. Believe it or not, in physics, we do not criticize people based off of ad hominum arguments.  Physicists criticize him because he *isn't a good physicist*.  His "theories" break the laws of physics, and are directly falsified by experiment (since 20-30 years ago at least).  The arguments in his book are fallacious, and do not represent what string theory actually says.  This is why no one in the theoretical physics community--which is much larger than the string community!--cites any of his papers or takes him seriously.  End of discussion.

Comment: @jeremy(continuation) Lee Smolin, a high calibre physicist, makes similar points.Finally, I want to emphasize  that I don't feel qualified to pass judgment on the value of string theory in physics (its value as fantastic source of inspiration for mathematicians is uncontroversial and acknowledged by Woit and all critics of string theory). But I think these issues should be settled according to the usual  procedures of scientific investigations and coming to a mathematics site with appeals to boycott a blog is not one of them.

Comment: @Grorges.  You aren't qualified. I am. So is the entire theoretical physics community.  They *have* passed judgment.  They don't cite Woit or Smolin's papers.  They don't take their work seriously.  They have been "settled according to the usual procedures of scientific investigations" **30 years ago**.   And it *is* appropriate to say this on a math website, when someone suggests (even indirectly) his blog, that it's no good, because, as you mentioned, not everyone here is qualified to see that it's total and complete nonsense.

Comment: I really do not think attacks on people for having "published no more than a dozen papers in his [career]" and "only three or so in the past decade or two" and having "almost no citations" belong on this website. Actually, its somewhat astonishing that someone would cite such superficial criteria, but regardless of merit, this sort of thing does not belong here. 

Comment: @alex. I would cite technical details, but it's not appropriate to go into a lengthy technical discussion here of why Woit and Smolin's theories are not taken seriously.  If you want to find out why, search the physics literature of the '70s-'80s regarding canonical quantization of general relativity and understand why they fail. Alternatively, Susskind, Weinberg, 't Hooft, and a few other **field theorists** have written lengthy criticisms of this over the years. I really am not exaggerating or being unfair when I say Woit and Smolin are not taken seriously by the entire community.

Comment: @jeremy You write: "You aren't qualified. I am." Thanks for this crisp summing-up of your arguments.

Comment: @jeremy Maybe, but attacking someone for not publishing enough papers or not racking up enough citations is low. Anyway, I would point out tht many mathematicians pursue research programs whose chances of success are viewed skeptically by others. 

Comment: @alex In physics, you're generally expected to, as a post doc, before applying to a position as a professor, have from 5-10 published papers, and to publish several papers a year if you're in a research-oriented position.  To only have ~10 papers published *ever* is pretty much unheard of.  Perhaps the situation is different in math?  I assumed otherwise, given the several volume collection of Milnor's published works I have next to me, but perhaps that is not the case!

Comment: @alex. I can also see what you're saying about mathematicians working on things others are "skeptical" of...  I have had this discussion more than once with mathematicians, so I should have learned my lesson by now...  In physics we, well, honestly, don't have the same standards of rigor as in math!  As a result, we're (typically) VERY generous (and overly polite) about what we think is potentially good work, and what's not. So for us to say someone's work is REALLY bad is the analog of a mathematician publishing papers with clearly false assertions and fallacious logical arguments.

Comment: I pronounce this comment thread officially closed. *One* more comment is allowed, which may only consist of a link to tea.mathoverflow.net announcing a thread to discuss the appropriateness of this discussion. Further, I'm going to use my moderator soapbox to say that I agree with Georges, that "You aren't qualified. I am." is a excellent representative of the ad hominem attacks some string theorists are so unfortunately prone to. Booyah. :-)

Comment: I regularly read Woit's blog exactly because it does great job of informing of recent developments in mathematics. I usually skip string theory part. 

Answer (score 4):

This is partly redundant with the answer of Victor Protsak, but I want to emphasize his point 3. The main reason I am very happy that my library has many paper subscriptions to math journals is that every week I have a dozen issues to browse. When the title of an article rings a bell, I take a look at the abstract and, sometimes, it convinces me to read the introduction or at least the main theorems. For some journals, e.g. Annals of Math or Acta, I read all abstract regardless of the subject. It is not uncommon that I cannot understand a word, but still I cross nice or important results in a large portion of the mathematical subjects.

This is clearly not sufficient to address your question, though: I had not heard of the works of Okounkov or Werner before they get their Fields medals.

Answer (score 1):

Here https://theorems.home.blog/theorems-list/ is the website you are asking for.

It covers all recently solved mathematical problems, which are important (for example, published in a top journal) but at the same time can be understood with not too much background.

Comment: See also his *Theorems of the 21st Century, Vol. 1*. [Springer link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030190958).