# List of recently solved mathematical problems

Tags: open-problems, problem-solving, big-list

I'm looking for a news site for Mathematics which particularly covers recently solved mathematical problems together with the unsolved ones. Is there a good site MO users can suggest me or is my only bet just to google for them?

Comment: There is a book "Unsolved problems in number theory" (which I don't find particularly fitting my taste). But this isn't a site and it covers some parts of number theory only. In any case, a response to "Is there a good site?" is no, as we can see from several discussions on MO about the state of art in many areas/problems.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26892/how-do-you-find-out-the-latest-news-in-fields-other-than-your-own

Comment: The Kourovka notebook is a good place to find unsolved problems in group theory, as well as problems from previous editions that have been recently solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a counter-point to my somewhat flippant previous answer (which only really applies if one is a specialist in the field), if you are looking at a field in which you are not as much a specialist in, I suggest reading the articles from the [Bulletin of the AMS](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/aboutbull). The articles are designed to be fairly up-to-date and expository in nature, and often gives the state of the art in their reviews.

Of course, a similar caveat as that to Helge's answer applies: the "news" maybe several months out of date. But considering the glacial paces at which a lot of mathematical refereeing takes place, I think it is quite okay.

In the spirit of this answer, you may also find [Which journals publish expository work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work) to be useful.

Comment: 
I also want to add the Notices of the AMS ( http://ams.org/notices ) to this list. 

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion  [Annals: to appear](http://pjm.math.berkeley.edu/scripts/coming.php?jpath=annals). Also other top journals. If a big problem gets solved, its solution probably gets submitted to a journal of this type, so its to appear lists are what you are looking for. Of course, you only learn about the solution of the problem a few years late (refereeing takes time), but you can be almost certain that the solution is actually correct.

Comment: There are many "bottom journals", for example, specialised ones, with better problems and nicer solutions. ("Top journals" indicate some kind of "mathematical fashion.")

Comment: @Wadim: I think your comment clearly illustrates that the original question needs clarification. Presumably every non-review/non-expository paper published solve *some* problem. The OP really ought to narrow down the question a bit. 

Comment: @Wadim: "big problem" is a "mathematical fashion" statement. Furthermore, there are plenty of reasons to care about "mathematical fashion", e.g. you want to get a job. But I'll stop here, since this line of discussion might get troublesome.

Comment: @Willie: Every nonmathematical question is imperfect! There is no need for clarification, all possible responses can be argued. Especially if they are imperfect (no examples, proofs--nothing specially convincing).

Comment: Yes, Helge, I am more than familiar with the job problem. And, yes, I also have to stop here, as it is a dangerous theme.

Comment: And +1 for your bravity!

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia page [List of unsolved problems in mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics) has a specific (and long) sublist for recently solved problems.

Comment: I think the correct link must be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for an active news site on Mathematics instead of Wikipedia.

Comment: The list of recently solved problems (with recently apparently meaning "Since 1977") is woefully short.

Comment: And missing many important developments.

Comment: Dan, Wikipedia is an open wiki project (I am being tautological...). Please, add important developments that you know, with references. 

Comment: I've been thinking about what to add.  I hope others will too!

Answer (score 2):

arXiv.org

Any paper worth reading *should* include some background material and a description of general progress in its introduction section. This is especially true of papers that actually *solve* a problem, rather than chipping away at some small technicality.

Comment: @Willie, but how to decide which paper is worth reading before looking inside? Even abstracts are hardly informative.

Comment: You don't expect somebody wanting to get an overview of recently solved problems in a subfield to wade through the enormous mass of papers that appear on arXiv every day, do you?

Comment: @Michal: yes.  As for "enormous mass", maybe you're thinking of physics.  In number theory (say), there are an average of perhaps 3-4 postings a day on the arXiv.  For the subfields of number theory that I am especially interested in, that amounts to a few papers a week.  P.S.: just because the papers appear every day doesn't mean you have to look every day...

Comment: @Michal: I read the listings for physics: hep-th, gr-qc, gen-ph, class-ph, hist-ph, soc-ph; and for maths: math.ap, math.ca, math.dg, math.fa, math-ph every day. Granted I do have a few years of experience in being able to quickly decide whether a paper is interesting or not (n.b. interesting $\neq$ quality). 

Comment: @Wadim: a corollary of what I said is that "if you are _not_ entrenched in the field, and if reading the introduction isn't helpful to your understanding of what's going on, then the paper is not going to be worth reading." I make no pretensions of being able to decide the "quality" of the reading by just the title and the abstract.

Comment: @Willie: I use the arxiv for informing colleagues in my area about novelties from my side (I e-notify) and check submissions from the others when I am e-notified. It's impossible to be selective with arXiv, and there is no fun in digging there.

Comment: @Wadim: I'm sure everyone uses arXiv in his or her own way, and I do not claim my way is better. On the other hand, I am not well established enough that people notify me when they have a new result (oh I envy your position). So the best way for me to keep on top of things is to follow arXiv postings. (BTW, I totally agree with your last sentence; I think of it as a rite-of-passage for early-careers like me.)

Comment: @Willie: yes, everyone uses it in his/her own way, and this does not really depends on the career stage but more on the environment, colleagues and personal opinion. I just wonder whether one can really get from arXiv a better understanding of open/solved problems. ArXiv is probably great for other things... I respect your opinion anyway!

Comment: I don't know how common it is across different fields, but I've seen quite a few helpful surveys and lists of open problems in geometric group theory on the arxiv that you would have hard time finding elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a list about group theory open problems here : http://www.grouptheory.info/

Answer (score 2):

Here https://theorems.home.blog/theorems-list/ is the website you are asking for.

It covers all recently solved mathematical problems, which are important (for example, published in a top journal) but at the same time can be understood with not too much background.